# Bash to list all json paths

Tags: json, bash

I have a `json` file and I want to list all the **paths** on it.
For example:
appsettings.json file:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "zuzu": {
    "lele": "lala"
  },
  "eita": [
    {
      "oxe": "right"
    }
  ]
}
```

the expected result is a array that contains (as a bash variable):

```json
[
  "foo",
  "zulu",
  "zuzu.lele",
  "eita",
  "eita.0",
  "eita.0.oxe"
]
```

I have tried the following with `jq` but I'm not able to iterate over the `jq` result and I'm clueless.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
join() {
    # $1 is return variable name
    # $2 is sep
    # $3... are the elements to join
    local retname=$1 sep=$2 ret=$3
    shift 3 || shift $(($#))
    printf -v "$retname" "%s" "$ret${@/#/$sep}"
}

jsonPaths=$(cat j.json | jq 'path(..)')

for path in $jsonPaths; do
  join pathString "." "${path[@]}"
  echo $path
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ jq '[ path(..) | join(".") ] | del(.[0])' /tmp/2.json
[
  "foo",
  "zuzu",
  "zuzu.lele",
  "eita",
  "eita.0",
  "eita.0.oxe"
]
```

Notes:

- `cat file | jq` is a useless use of `cat`. Do `jq ... file`
- to convert to a bash array, use the usuall `readarray -t arr < <(jq -r ....)`
- `jq` has a quite capable programming language. First try to solve problems in `jq`.